# How to add contains filter from Kibana dashboard?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to add a filter say to display all the `@log_name` and `log` that contain say `test` keyword. I am seeing following fields on Kibana dashboard.

- log
- @log_name
- _id
- _index
- hostname

When I add a filter with `@log_name is test` it is not returning any results but when I add `log is test` it returns all the values that contain this keyword.

I also tried `@log_name is *test*` and `@log_name.keyword is *test*` and I am not getting any results. I have following three questions here:

*1. How can I add a filter that returns the values that contain `test` in `@log_name`?*

*Update: I figured out the way to add wildcard by editing query DSL.*

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "@log_name": {
        "value": "*test*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2. Why I am able to search `log` containing `test` and not `@log_name`?
3. What does @fieldName, _fieldName, fieldName mean on Kibana dashbaord?

Comment: Please give us more information about the data type of your fields. Is 'log' and '@log_name' text and/or keyword?

Comment: I am sending docker logs where log is the message and @log_name is the docker container name. I am not sure what you mean by text or keyword.

Answer (score 0):

When you index a doc to Elasticsearch it creates a mapping that defines the type of each field (string or text, long, keyword, etc). When you query a text field that is analyzed, you search above all the tokens (generally words that composes a phrase) of the field so surely your log file is making a match with the word "test" with a token of this field. Maybe the @log_name field has another configuration so check out the mapping.

Some doc that may help:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html

I'm not pretty sure what you mean with your third question as all of this depends of the mapping, the name of the field should not matter.